# How to send image and JSON object data in android by using MultipartEntityBuilder and HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android

Since API level 22 android deprecate the HTTP Client and Multi part Builder. I want to send some JSON object and images on server in a single request by using MultipartEntityBuilder and HttpURLConnection.

Comment: MultipartEntityBuilder is also deprecated in API23 :)

Comment: Than what should be used ? @BNK

Answer (score 1):

> Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android was intended to remedy the
>   situation by providing official releases compatible with Google
>   Android.
>
> Given that as of Android API 23 Google's fork of HttpClient has been
>   removed this project has been discontinued.
>
> Those users who want to continue using Apache HttpClient on Android
>   are advised to consider

Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android when targeting Android API 22 and older

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

Apache HttpClient packages for Android maintained by Marek Sebera when targeting Android API 23 and newer

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

taken from **Apache Official Website** : [Apache HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html)

**NOTE:** You do not have to use `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` statement, which was introduced for projects that didn't migrate from Android provided HttpClient classes. For further [explanation](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/wiki/Project-Introduction).

I have implemented a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/b96488c612c1f150a1da) doing **MultipartRequest(File Upload) using Volley**.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully send the image file and JSON data by using Multipart Entity Builder and HttpOpenUrl connection,by using below code.

```
        String boundary = "*************";
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(image));//pass your image path to make a file
        builder.addPart("profile_image", fileBody);
        builder.addPart("data", new StringBody(jsonObject.toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));//pass our jsonObject  here
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("write your url here");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", entity.getContentLength() + "");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            os.close();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String s = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(s);
            }
            serverResponseMessage = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Together with my comment, because of the deprecation of Apache's librabry from API22, suggest that you use HttpUrlConnection, [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)... instead.

You should read more [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Relating to OkHttp's sample for multipart requests, please refer to [its GitHub documentation here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

Hope this helps!