# Unable to use NameValuePair in Android Studio

Tags: android, arraylist, deprecated, basicnamevaluepair

I want to upload data to a server from my android application.For this I want to use NameValuePair in my code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));
```

But unfortunately NameValuePair is deprecated now.What are the posssible alternatives to this and how can I upload image without using NameValuePair?

Comment: Try to use Multipart Entity Builder.                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041906/how-to-send-image-and-json-object-data-in-android-by-using-multipartentitybuilde

Comment: Multipart Entity Builder is also deprecated.Please suggest another approach.